# Importing python file in docker container

Tags: python, docker

I'm executing a python file inside a docker container, and need to import all the functions that I put into a separate python file called `base_functions`. However, writing `from base_functions import *` throws the error, that `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base_functions'`, even though `base_functions.py` is in the same directory as the main python file. How can I do this? Do I need to specify which python scripts I want to import beforehand, in the settings.ini or something?

This is the content of the Dockerfile:

```
FROM amancevice/pandas:0.24.1-alpine

RUN apk update
RUN apk add build-base
RUN apk add gcc musl-dev libc-dev util-linux-dev linux-headers python3-dev postgresql-libs postgresql-dev git libffi-dev libmemcached-dev zlib-dev \
            ca-certificates zlib-dev jpeg-dev freetype-dev libpng

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY src /vdp

WORKDIR /

ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "-m", "vdp"]
```

These are all the files in the directory of the project:

```
/home/cr/docker/71119/.

├── docker-compose.yaml
├── Dockerfile
├── Makefile
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── settings.ini
└── src
    ├── base_functions.py
    ├── influx.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── __main__.py
```

Comment: Have you tried using `from .base_functions import *`?

Comment: yes, it returns the same error :(

Comment: Then maybe the files are not in the same directory, if will be helpful if can you share your Dockerfile and your folders structure to know a bit more about your issue

Comment: ive edited the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're practically renaming your package (it smells like a package, having `__init__.py` and `__main__.py`) from "src" to "vdp" when you're creating the dockerfile.

I'd recommend:

- Rename `src/...` to `src/vdp/...` (or `vdp/...`) 
  – at this point you should be able to run `python -m vdp` within the `src` directory on your host machine and things should work.
- Change the Dockerfile stanzas to
  `COPY src /src`
  `WORKDIR /src`
  `ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "-m", "vdp"]`
  – this'd be equivalent to how you're running it on the host machine.

Another option would be to drop the `/src` in the repository and change things to `COPY vdp /src/vdp`.

The third option, of course, would be to set up proper Python packaging, have your `setup.py` build a proper wheel, then simply install that in the Docker container.

Comment: after renaming the folders I am able to run  `python -m vdp` within the src directory. However, If I exchange the copy, workdir and entrypoint lines for the ones you posted, I still get the same error.

Comment: Might be a silly typo on my part. You can enter the container interactively using `docker run -it image-id-here bash` and examine the situation in `/src`.

Comment: You need to change `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD` for that to work.  (You should, there’s not really a downside.)

Comment: @AKX Wouldn't the COPY command copy the entire directory? Why aren't the import locations preserved?

Answer (score 1):

Python is not able to find the file base_functions because it was run from other folder.

You may want to change the working directory of in the Dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR /path/to/workdir
```

Comment: this leads to the error "| /usr/bin/python3: No module named vdp"

Answer (score 1):

You need to mention the PYTHONPATH. In your Dockerfile, I'm gonna assume your root dir is `/home/cr/docker/71119/src/`

```
env PYTHONPATH /home/cr/docker/71119/src/
```

Either that, or if you wanna see it working (my preference for debugging)

`docker run -it <img-name> /bin/bash`

`export PYTHONPATH=/home/cr/docker/71119/src/ && python3 <your-script>.py` And it should work.

Another *tip* is that if you want to show the file structure, install tree by: `apt-get install tree -y && cd <your-dir> && tree` And then post that to SO. It's just cleaner!

Comment: Modifying `PYTHONPATH` is generally not a good idea and can lead to confusion such as the same file being accessible with two different imports.