# Importing python files in Docker container

Tags: python, docker, python-import

When running my docker image, I get an import error:

```
File "./app/main.py", line 8, in <module>
import wekinator
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wekinator'`
```

How do I import local python modules in Docker? Wouldn't the COPY command copy the entire "app" folder (including both files), hence preserving the correct import location?

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
└── app
    ├── main.py
    └── wekinator.py
```

```
FROM python:3.7

RUN pip install fastapi uvicorn python-osc

EXPOSE 80

COPY ./app /app

CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing python file in docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58804751/importing-python-file-in-docker-container)

Comment: i suggest to create the running file main.py running function outside of app folder, and from that folder run the docker image, why error is coming because of the location from where you are running your docker and webinator is not present there

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'm aware of this post. What I don't understand is the COPY command – wouldn't I be copying the entire app folder (including both files), hence preserving the correct import location?

Comment: Is the content of the `app` directory the top-level package (as in your `import` statement) or the `app` package (as in the `uvicorn` command line)?

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks, that finally cleared some of my confusion. I've changed my  WORDIR to app but now I get the error message `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named app`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the `PYTHONPATH` as such works but feels clumsy:

```
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/app/"
```

Using Docker's `WORKDIR` allows for a much cleaner solution:

```
FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR /code

RUN pip install fastapi uvicorn python-osc

EXPOSE 80

COPY app ./app

CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

Note how the `COPY` statement changed.

Comment: Comprehensive and works like a charm!

Answer (score 9):

After much confusion, I got the container to run by setting a PYTHONPATH env variable in the Dockerfile:

```
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/app/"
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to see which `WORKDIR` you’re using on your install.

Seems that you’re trying to execute the script from your workdir but you’re copying the data to your root folder inside your container.

Create your docker, run it and check if the files copied in `COPY` command are in the right folder.

You can do this running `docker compose exec <name of your container> ls` and check if the `ls` command lista the folder that you’re trying to call.